# In Maven how do I copy files using the wagon plugin?

Tags: maven, wagon, maven-wagon-plugin, maven-webstart-plugin

Summary: How do I copy some generated files into a webserver (eg IIS or Apache) directory using Maven?

Details:
I have a working application that builds in Maven. I've managed to get it building using the [webstart-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/) which produces all the needed files (.jar and .jnlp) in a directory `target/jnlp`. It also creates a zip file with them all in at `target/foo-1.0.zip`.

At the moment the webstart plugin does not have a `deploy` goal - the request for it has ended up on the [FAQ (question 3)](http://mojo.codehaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/faq.html). It may be implemented in future, but the suggestion for the time being is to use [wagon-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html).

I've never used Wagon. To start with I'd like to just copy the files to a local directory served up by a webserver. Later I'd like to copy them remotely, probably using ftp. Can someone give an example to what I need to add to the `pom.xml` to get the local copy working (and hopefully an ftp example too?). I can't find it in the documentation. From reading I think I might also need the [Wagon Maven File Provider](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-file/) but as this seems to have almost no documentation I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6):

Wagon providers are only there to provide additional network protocol supports (such as FTP).

If you want to copy file to a webserver (local or distant) you can use Maven upload plugin :

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-upload-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
...
```

In parent pom :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-upload-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resourceSrc>
                        ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}
                    </resourceSrc>
                    <resourceDest>${jboss.deployDir}</resourceDest>
                    <serverId>${jboss.host}</serverId>
                    <url>${jboss.deployUrl}</url>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And to configure parameters in a smart way, I use maven profiles (in parent pom) :

```
<profiles>
    <!-- local deployment -->
    <profile>
        <id>developpement</id>
        <properties>
            <jboss.host>localhost</jboss.host>
            <jboss.deployDir>appli/jboss-4.0.4.GA/server/default/deploy/</jboss.deployDir>
            <jboss.deployUrl>file://C:/</jboss.deployUrl>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- distant deployment -->
    <profile>
        <id>validation</id>
        <properties>
            <jboss.host>ENV_val</jboss.host>
            <jboss.deployDir>/home/envval/jboss/server/default/deploy/</jboss.deployDir>
            <jboss.deployUrl>scp://PROJECT_LAN_HOST</jboss.deployUrl>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I've created an "ant launcher", to use it by clicking under Eclipse ant view :

```
<target name="copy war to JBoss local" description="Copy war to local JBoss">
    <maven goal="upload:upload" options="-Pdeveloppement" />
</target>
```

But you can simply run it on a command line :

```
mvn upload:upload -Pdeveloppement
```

**EDIT** : By the way, for distant deployment, you may need a login password for scp to work. You have to add them to you Maven settings.xml file :

```
<settings>
  ...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ENV_val</id>
      <username>login</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```

**EDIT**: You'll need to add the Atlassian repository:

```
    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>Atlassian</id>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

**EDIT**: depending upong the remote protocol you'll have to add wagon extensions, see [Uploading a directory using sftp with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816909/uploading-a-directory-using-sftp-with-maven)

Comment: Hi, could you extend your answer to show a copy to a local server? The docs don't seem great for the upload plugin either.

Answer (score 3):

In the end I didn't use the Maven upload plugin - it seemed a bit limited and not part of the main maven distribution. I used the maven wagon plugin as suggested. Here is the simplest possible pom that I could make that worked. Hopefully others will find it useful, as I couldn't find anything similar easily.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <configuration>
      <fromDir>${project.build.directory}/jnlp</fromDir>
      <includes>*</includes>
      <url>file://c:/inetpub/wwwroot</url>
      <toDir>jnlp</toDir>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

For remote distributions, you just change the URL type, and possibly add wagon extensions as necessary.

Comment: You shouldn't use wagon-maven-plugin to do this (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493522/problem-uploading-with-maven-wagon-plugin). Also neither wagon-maven-plugin nor maven-upload-plugin are from org.apache.maven, they are from org.codehaus.mojo and com.atlassian.maven.plugins

Comment: Thanks for that info - feels very odd. I'll probably stick with it for now, but I think I'd rather rely on codehaus than atlassian for now. I'll keep searching for a better solution

Comment: @Tristan, codehaus and maven were close friends ;).